# How to get a list of changed files before pulling from the main repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I need to get a list of changed files from before actually pulling the new/modified files from the main repository.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use incoming command:**

To tell us what changes the hg pull command would pull into the repository, without actually pulling the changes in

```
hg incoming
```

Also, for remote repository, using `--bundle` avoids downloading the changesets twice if the incoming is followed by a pull.

See: http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html

Comment: To get the actual files, you should add `--verbose` or `--patch` depending on what type of information you're after. +1 for the `--bundle` option.

Comment: Or --stat if you just want the list of filenames and a barchart showing how much they changed.